# Pygame Screen tearing when moving line across screen

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi, vsync

I am trying to move this image:

[image]

Across my PyGame screen, from right to left and back again, However as the image moves, every second or so I have a flicker of screen tear make its way up the image like so:

[image]

**The code I am using is a loop similar to this:**

```
screen.blit(img, (x,y))
pygame.update((x,y),(w,h))
pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),((x,y),(w,h)))
```

**So far I have tried the following to solve the issue:**

Using `HWSURFACE`, `FULLSCREEN`, `DOUBLEBUF` flags when creating the screen, this had no effect, I also adjusted my `.update(rect)` to a `.flip()` (as this is recommended when using `DOUBLEBUF`?)

Splitting the memory between GPU and CPU (I am running this on a raspberry pi 2) I have tried giving both more memory, no change.

Setting a clock.tick to throttle the update rate to 60 FPS (above and below as well) this did smooth out some of the tearing but not all

Adjusting the size of each increment left or right, making the increments smaller results in less tearing, but also less speed. (Can't have it going *too* slow)

Blitting a new black surface rather than drawing a black rect over the previous position (when moving the image to ensure there is no trail behind it) as I read somewhere that `blit` is better supported with `HWSURFACE` than drawing, although I can't confirm this? - This had no effect

**If anyone has any other solutions that may improve the situation I'd be grateful.**

I would rather *not* change from PyGame to anything else (like pyglet) as I have done quite a lot of implementation so far using PyGame, but I am open to suggestions.

Cheers

**EDIT**

Relevant code as requested:

```
if scanner == True:
    clocker.tick(clockspeed)
    if x < 11:
        slower = 3
        if firstTime == True:
            img.set_alpha(int(x * 25))
            newSurf.set_alpha(int(x * 25))
            screen.blit(newSurf,(xText,35))
            pygame.display.update((xText,35),((xText + newSurf.get_width()),(50 + newSurf.get_height())))
            img.set_alpha(255)

    elif x > (divider - 15):
        slower = 3
    else:
        slower = 0
        firstTime = False

    screen.blit(img, ((xStart - (x * increment) + slower),100))
    pygame.display.update(((xStart - (x * increment) + slower),100),(95,450))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (((xStart - (x * increment) + slower),100),(95,450)))
```

The `slower` variable is to give a feel of inertia as the bar reaches the far left and right sides of its sweep across the speed it will slow down a little.

The `firstTime` variable is for fading in the bar when it first appears.

There is another loop just below this that is very similar, but sweeps the image back the other way.

Comment: I know that the code you provided us is a *pseudo-code*, but **why do you first update the screen and after that draw the rect**? Btw it should be `pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),((x,y),(w,h)))` since the third parameter is a `pygame.Rect` object :)

Comment: Ah yes, missed our a few brackets when throwing up the pseudo, I will edit now, good spot! :) and I draw the rect after the update because this runs in a loop, and the rect is to draw over the previous position of the image, I could move the rect draw to the first line of code and it would behave the same

Comment: No trouble at all :) If it is possible for you, could you post your main game loop code?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't actually a game, I am using pygame so I can make a nice looking GUI for my Python program. Give me a minute and I will post the relevant section of code

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
vsync = true
```

in `pygame.display.set_mode()`

Answer (score 0):

this tearing is just the product of the way that screens render. The next position for the line is rendering while the previous position is being drawn over. If the refresh rate and update rate for the screen are synchronous then this problem disappears. But since that it near impossible to do accurately, I'd suggest making your program take the route that PICO-8 takes in managing this, waiting for a screen refresh to finish before changing the screen buffer to prevent tearing. I'm not sure if there is a method for waiting for a screen refresh to finish, but if there is, then the sequence should go: `update back buffer -> wait for screen to stop being drawn -> flip buffers -> screen is drawn again`.

A refresh is where the screen is drawn left to right, top to bottom, pixel by pixel. This is because the triple BUS connection to the screen only lets the brightness for one pixel at a time come from the screen memory, so each one is drawn sequentially. The tearing comes from that memory changing midway through a refresh so the line moves position midway down the screen.